# Looping through array of object data within Falcor

Tags: angularjs, falcor, falcor-router

Let's say I have the following routes:

```
{
  route: "usersById['length']",
  get: function(pathSet) {}
},
{
  route: "usersById[{integers:ids}]['firstName', 'lastName']",
  get: function(pathSet) {}
}
```

With the following in my angular1 controller:

```
Model.get(
  'usersById.length',
  'usersById[0..2]['firstName', 'lastName']'
).then(function(response) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    vm.entities = response.json.usersById;
  });
});
```

The response from the server is going to look something like:

```
{
  jsonGraph: {
    usersById: {
      "0": {
        firstName: 'Jiminy',
        lastName: 'Cricket'
      },
      "1": {
        firstName: 'Jafar',
        lastName: 'Husain'
      },
      "length": 123123
    }
  }
}
```

In my angular 1 template, I want to loop through the list of users:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entity in users.entities">
  <td>{{entity.firstName}} {{entity.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that there aren't just users in the response, firstly it contains `length` and secondly it seems other meta data is returned by Model's promise, of which looks to be part of the path data: `usersById`

What is the preferred way of looping through the list of users? Should I doing something like this in my promise?

```
vm.entities = response.json.usersById.filter(function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'object';
});
```

I'm not seeing any API call for fetching raw values anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems the correct way to handle this is to create another route: `users` which just returns `usersById` references, that way you have an array of just entities, not containing length etc.

I'm guessing having the path data in the array of data was just a bug.

```
{
    users: {...},
    usersById: {...}
}

<li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.firstName }}</li>
```